# How to express tree structure constraints

Tags: uml, diagram, ocl

How can the following constraints be expressed:

**1 - There is exactly one folder that is not a sub-directory to another directory.**
(I couldn't fully understand the folder/subfolder theme and how to describe the only one possible  exclusion from the folder system)

And there are also some question which comes from the first question

**2 The highest nesting of folders does not exceed the number n.**

**3) The total number of files on your system can not exceed the number n.**

**4) The total number of files (subdirectory) in a given system cannot exceed the number n.**

[image: The uml diagram]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Edited. I should define in UML the listed constraints

Comment: probably *a sub-directory **to** another directory* means *a sub-directory **of** another directory* . What is the goal of `(subdirectory)` in 4 ? Why in 1 and 2 there is no reference to the system but in 3 and 4 it is *your system* and *a given system* ? The statement is not clear at all, I can only say you to use *constraints* typically in OCL for these requirements, but I cannot help more while the statement is not clear

Comment: I still don't see the question. The constraints are defined already.

Comment: Are you looking for OCL constraints maybe? Most of these constraints can't be expressed using simple multiplicities of associations.

Comment: Thank all of you, guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your four constraints cannot be expressed simply using the multiplicities.

In UML theses constraints can be written using OCL, see [formal/2014-02-03](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.4)

Of course the constraints can be written in a class diagram, for instance see figure 7.14 *Constraint in a note symbol* page 37 of [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1).

> **1 - There is exactly one folder that is not a sub-directory to another directory**

one way to write that is :

```
Folder.allInstances()->select(f | f.upfolder->isEmpty())->size() = 1
```

where

- `Folder.allInstances()` return the instances of the class *Folder*
- `Folder.allInstances()->select(f | f.upfolder->isEmpty())` iterate on the instances and return the instances having no *upfolder*
- `Folder.allInstances()->select(f | f.upfolder->isEmpty())->size() = 1` then checks there is one folder without *upfolder*

> **2 The highest nesting of folders does not exceed the number n**

one way is to define a function computing the depth of a folder then to check all the folder have a depth less or equals to *n*

```
context Folder
def: depth() : Integer =
  if upfolder->notEmpty() then
    upfolder->first().depth() + 1
  else
    0

Folder.allInstances()->forAll(f | f.depth() <= n)
```

where `forAll` is true if the condition `depth() <= n` is true for all the elements

But it is only useful to compute the depth of the folders without sub folder, so

```
Folder.allInstances()
  ->select(f | f.subfolder->isEmpty())
     ->forAll(f | f.depth() <= n)
```

> **3) The total number of files on your system can not exceed the number n.**
>
> **4) The total number of files (subdirectory) in a given system cannot exceed the number n.**

I do not understand why `(subdirectory)` in **4** nor why **3** says `on your system` and **4** says `a given system` while there is nothing about *system* in **1** and **2**.

Supposing the goal is to check the total number of files is less or equals to *n* and the files of a folder are given by the attribute *file* :

```
Folder.allInstances()->collect(f | f.file.size()).sum() <= n
```

where

- `Folder.allInstances()->collect(f | f.file.size())` returns the collection of the number of files for all the folders
- `Folder.allInstances()->collect(f | f.file.size()).sum()` return the total number of files

Comment: Amazing! You are really **THE** ocl guru here!

Comment: @Christophe thank you, yes few people do OCL, and in fact I only use OCL to answer on S.O. so I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

The use of allInstances() is discouraged.

1. It is very desirable to have some FileSystem class that has exactly one root Folder, therefore guaranteeing the constraint in a simple multiplicity.
2. Is easily handled by a [0..3] multiplicity declaration.
3. A depth() helper helpfully cached by a derived property is a good solution.

Or just:  context File inv: Folder->closure(upFolder).size() < n

3. context Folder inv: self->closure(subfolder).File->size() < n

Comment: `The use of allInstances() is discouraged` : by who ? from where you get that ? why, for performance reasons ? OCL is very far of concept of performances. Out of that in the statement does not give a way to access the instances so no other choice

Comment: `1. It is very desirable to have  ...` : for sure to have the root(s) of the filesystem is the right way ... but nothing about that in the statement, so have to do in an other way

Comment: `2. Is easily handled by a [0..3] multiplicity declaration` : multiplicity on what ? why 0..3 ?  and how a multiplicities can handle the depth of a folder ?

Comment: `3. A depth() helper helpfully cached by a derived property is a good solution.` : first the depth is for `2.`rather than `3.`, and for sure if we don't have to compute the depth it is better, but first that does not exist in the statement, second that must be update each time a folder must be moved, and third notice that information does not exist in 'standard' file system. So I indicate a way to compute it

Comment: `3. context Folder inv: self->closure(subfolder).File->size() < n`: out of my doubt about closure (this is why I do not used it) the question is about the system, so only interesting when *self* is the (non directly available) root of the file system. Of course if this is true for any folder it is also for the root(s)